# Hibernate HQL LEFT JOIN not performing same as equivalent SQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Cannot work out why these two statements return a different number of results. They should be the same. The SQL version (correctly) returns 2 results and the HQL version returns (incorrectly) 3 results.

The output of the SQL returns 3 results of tb2.user with values 1, null and null. The where clause means this filters down to 2 results, removing the result with a tb2.user value of 1. However, the HQL version returns 3 results. I would like the HQL to return 2 results.

### My SQL

`SELECT * FROM table1 as tb1 LEFT JOIN table2 as tb2 ON tb1.user = tb2.blocked WHERE tb2.user <> 1 OR tb2.user is null;`

### My HQL

`SELECT r FROM table1 tb1 LEFT JOIN table2 tb2 ON tb1.user.id = tb2.user.id WHERE tb2.user.id <> :userId OR tb2.user.id is null GROUP BY tb1`

Any help on this is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you miss `GROUP BY` ?? Those are not equal

Comment: Sorry yes, I have removed the `GROUP BY` from the HQL statement but still the same

Comment: Basically, the SQL returns tb2.user values of 1, null and null. Where as the HQL statement returns tb2.user values of null, null and null.

Comment: What is `r`?  The `select`s are different.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use left joined  table's column in where condition .. this work as  an inner join
you should move these condition in the related  ON clause

and in the second query  ( My HQL) you have an improper group by without aggregation function  (so the query are not equivalent)
(when you need  distinct result  .. use Distinct clause )

```
  SELECT r 
  FROM table1 tb1 
  LEFT JOIN table2 tb2 ON tb1.user.id = tb2.user.id 
    AND  ( tb2.user.id <> :userId OR tb2.user.id is null )
```

Comment: I think that query optimizer will do that anyway. Not sure, but thats my bet as it is very common scenario.

Comment: .. @Antoniossss   if the condition  is in WHERE clause the the LEFT JOIN is broken and work as  a INNER JOIN  ...  the use of GROUP BY without aggregation function id deprecated  in most DB db brand is not allowed  in most recent version of the main  db  mysql included .

Comment: Thank you for your response! However, I have tried the above and I still get 3 results, where I should be getting back 2. It looks like my tb2.user.id value is always Null for the HQL statement. It should be 1, null, null. I have also removed the `GROUP BY`

Comment: @scaisEdge that is something i just disagree as it would be naive. IMHO it works just the same (due to query optimizer magic )PS. i meant join related part.